# Can I set flags as 0 in PendingIntent.getService

Tags: android

The Code 1 and Code 2 are create a pendingIntent object, but in some samples code it writed as Code 1 , and in some other samples code it writed as Code 2. Which one is correct? Thanks!

**Code 1**

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext,
                0,
                new Intent(mContext, CleanupService.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

**Code 2**

```
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext,
                0,
                new Intent(mContext, CleanupService.class),
                0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flag basically represents a single bit of information in an int, which is why their values are always powers of 2. And why you can set multiple flags with a bitwise or:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext,
    0,
    new Intent(mContext, CleanupService.class),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

Your two code blocks do different things and neither is more "correct" than the other.

`FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` will basically cancel all existing pending intents that would launch an equivalent intent

`0` corresponds to all flags off

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean "0 corresponds to all flags off" ?

Comment: You're asking what all flags off means? Or do you not know what 0 I'm referring to?

Comment: Yes, could you tell me what all flags off mean?

Comment: And more, from the document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html, I can't find I can pass 0 to the flags

Comment: Thanks! I just learned Bit field. Could you tell me what all flags off mean?

Comment: Yeah... so if you for example had three flags switched on you would have 111 in binary, or 7 in decimal. If you switch them off you would have 000 in binary or 0 in decimal.

Comment: Thanks! I know that I have the value 000 in binary if I switch them off, I want to know how PendingIntent is created, will it always be created a new one if I switch them off?

Comment: Yes, the only way it wouldn't is if you used the `FLAG_NO_CREATE` flag.